# Docker Container server not sending data

Tags: python, docker, flask

I've just started learning docker and I'm trying to run a very simple flask server in a container. Whenever I run it, it works just fine. However, when I access the website, chrome displays this:

```
This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir /test
WORKDIR /test
RUN pip3 install flask

COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000

cmd ["python3", "application.py"]
```

And the commands I'm using to build the image and run the container:

```
docker build . -t test
docker start -p 5000:5000 test
```

Could someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`localhost` inside the container is different from `localhost` outside the container.

Change

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

to

```
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try exposing port 80

```
EXPOSE 80
```

And start the container as root:

```
sudo docker start -p 80:80 test
```

Comment: I'm on windows (sadly)

Comment: Flask uses port 5000 as it's development server. I ran the server on my computer (not through a container) and it worked

Comment: I see. Well its hard to tell whats wrong then. Maybe full path on the python3 command? Log into the container and see if everything runs correctly: docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash

Comment: What do you mean? If it helps, I tried running a webserver using Go (golang:latest) and it didn't work as well (same problem). When I tried running the golang server on my static (lan) ip address (not 127.0.0.1 or localhost) the container just exited right after starting.

Comment: I meant running cmd ["/usr/bin/python3", "application.py"]

Comment: when I do that, this happens:File "application.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Comment: Just so you know, the server runs successfully in the container (I get the usual flask output telling me the URL its running on, etc.) The problem is that I am unable to access said URL from my main machine.

Comment: Hm. Are you calling the website with port 5000 in the url? "localhost:5000" ?

Comment: yes i am ______

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228327/discussion-between-r3dapple-and-serket).